# Help with showing text when something is entered in my search bar

Tags: wp-query, loop, search, forms

I'm having troubles replacing text when there is something entered in the search form.
As you can see in the image below i want to replace 'mijn gemeente' with the `get_search_query` text if i'm searching something, if nothing is searched it should show 'mijn gemeente'.

[image]

Comment: where is your search input? show the code, sharing snapshot of the code makes us to help more difficult

Comment: Search input is in my sidebar. I can get the text from the input and show it but i want it only to show if there was anything searched. When there is nothing searched it should show 'mijn gemeente'.
So basically i need some sort of IF loop i think.

Comment: I found it out, thanks for the help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jQuery's `focus` function. add following into your php file inside `<script>` tags.

```
$("#your-searchinput-id").focus(function() {
    $("h4.title_sidebarsub").text("<?php echo $string ?>")
});
$(this).blur(function() {
    $("h4.title_sidebarsub").text("mijn gemeente")
});
```

Comment: I found it out, thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: @Dennis you can accept the answer if it helps you.. good luck